# Grails request.getFile always returning null

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, groovy, grails-controller, grails-3.0

I've been trying to submit a form that contains multiple inputs (texts and one image) but I'm unable to retrieve the image from request (Grails 3.0.4)

My create.gsp looks like this:

```
<g:uploadForm controller="advertisement" action="save">

   <input name="name" type="text" id="advertisement_name" />

   <input name="link" type="text" id="advertisement_url" />

   <input id="add_banner_image" name="myimage" type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" data-max-size="512000"/>

   <g:submitButton name="save" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" value="Salvar anúncio">
   </g:submitButton>

</g:uploadForm>
```

My browser shows the correct request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarysaAgHUi2q9vTfkkY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Filipe
------WebKitFormBoundarysaAgHUi2q9vTfkkY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="link"

https://www.filipescosta.com
------WebKitFormBoundarysaAgHUi2q9vTfkkY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagemlouca"; filename="exemplo.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarysaAgHUi2q9vTfkkY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="save"

Salvar anúncio
```

My resources.groovy looks like this:

```
beans = {
    multipartResolver (org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver) {
        maxUploadSize=2500000
    }
}
```

And my application.yml looks like this:

```
grails:
mime:
    disable:
        accept:
            header:
                userAgents:
                    - Gecko
                    - WebKit
                    - Presto
                    - Trident
    types:
        all: '*/*'
        atom: application/atom+xml
        css: text/css
        csv: text/csv
        form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        html: 
          - text/html
          - application/xhtml+xml
        js: text/javascript
        json:
          - application/json
          - text/json
        multipartForm: multipart/form-data
        pdf: application/pdf
        rss: application/rss+xml
        text: text/plain
        hal: 
          - application/hal+json
          - application/hal+xml
        xml:
          - text/xml
          - application/xml
urlmapping:
    cache:
        maxsize: 1000
controllers:
    defaultScope: singleton
converters:
    encoding: UTF-8
views:
    default:
        codec: html
    gsp:
        encoding: UTF-8
        htmlcodec: xml
        codecs:
            expression: html
            scriptlets: html
            taglib: none
            staticparts: none
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
def save() {
    println request.getFile('myimage')
    println "Request class: ${request.class}"
    [...]

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'advertisement.label', default: 'Advertisement'), advertisement.id])
            redirect(uri:'/')
        }
        '*' { respond advertisement, [status: CREATED, formats:['html']] }
    }
}
```

But in console, the println message is:

```
null
Request class: class org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest
```

Can anyone take a look and help me with some trick? I've been searching examples and I couldn't find anything that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You define: attribute name="myimage"
and try get with Uppercase name -> request.getFile('myImage')

Comment: Oh, it's an copy/paste mistake. I didn't miss it in my code, but I figured out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what was going on.

I was trying to create a new object with String type, but I was sending an input file type as a parameter.
Then, after trying to set the input type String to a file type, the code broke and I wasn't able to print the value of request.getFile.